# Python parse standalone-full.xml from Wildfly

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse the standalone-full.xml from Wildfly 8.1 Final with python to extract some information as datasources.

The example XML below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.1">
<profile>
       <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/JNDI" pool-name="JNDI" enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOST</connection-url>
                <driver>ojdbc6</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>50</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>USER</user-name>
                    <password>USER</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>10000</background-validation-millis>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="ojdbc6" module="oracle.ojdbc">
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.ojdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
 </profile>
```

EDIT: How can I get deeper in the tree?

I tried something like this:

```
In[16]: from lxml import etree
In[18]: xml = etree.parse('standalone-full.xml')
In[21]: root = xml.getroot()
In[28]: children = root[0].getchildren()
In[31]: children[0]
Out[31]: <Element {urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0}subsystem at 0x4bef208>
In[32]: datasources = children[0]
In[33]: datasources.getchildren()
Out[33]: [<Element {urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0}datasources at 0x4befa48>]
```

Comment: Go through the [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) and rephrase the question if you couldn't resolve.

Comment: @WoodChopper: Thanks, didn't see that site. Helped a little. Rewrote the question and adapted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather unspecific, but as far as I can see from the regex you posted, you want to grab the text values of the `connection-url`, `user-name`, and `password` nodes under each `datasource` node that has a `pool-name` attribute with a value of `JNDI`. Here is one possibility of doing that (tested under Python 2.7):

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

ns = {'ds': 'urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0'}
root = ET.parse('standalone-full.xml').getroot()
children = root.findall(".//ds:datasource[@pool-name='JNDI']", ns)

for child in children:
    print child.find("ds:connection-url", ns).text
    security = child.find("ds:security", ns)
    print security.find("ds:user-name", ns).text
    print security.find("ds:password", ns).text
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Augeas to parse it:

```
$ augtool -At "Xml.lns incl $PWD/standalone-full.xml"
augtool> get //standalone-full.xml//datasource//password/#text
//standalone-full.xml//datasource//password/#text = USER
```

Just use the python-augeas bindings with Python:

```
import augeas
a = augeas.Augeas(flags=augeas.Augeas.NO_MODL_AUTOLOAD)
a.transform("Xml", "/home/raphink/bas/augeas/standalone-full.xml")
a.load()
v = a.get("//standalone-full.xml//datasource//password/#text")
```

Comment: Another CLI Interface is not an option as this code should run as a webservice. EDIT: Can it run with namespaces? Because I'll reuse the code for other settings too. And a `key` field can be a duplicate.

Comment: @JinnFox As suggested, use the Python bindings (I added an example, using python-augeas 0.5.0 from pypi). I'm not sure to get your question about namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with regex which is a bad idea but it works.

```
import re
data = "standalone-full.xml"
regex_result = re.findall(r'.*:domain:datasources[\S\s]*?pool-name="JNDI"[\S\s]*?connection-url>.*' +
                                      '@//(.*)<.*[\S\s]*?user-name>(.*)<.*\s*<password>(.*)<', data, re.M)
```